# React Localhost unresponsive from one component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

When I saw the issue the first thing I did is find the culprit which ended up being the component holding a simple image.  When I remove it the project works fine, however, I need it for my project and I  can't see what went wrong for it to crash the localhost and it's becoming extremely frustrating. If I can get help and see what I'm not seeing it would be extremely appreciated.

Container (parent)

```
import React from 'react';
import { CardItem } from './card-item';
import {PlayArrow,Add,ThumbUpAltOutlined,ThumbDownAltOutlined} from '@material-ui/icons';

export function CardItemContainer() {
    return(
            <CardItem>


{/*Cause of crash */}
   CardItem.CardPicture src="/images/misc/hxh.jpg" alt="Feature Picture" />                
{/*Cause of crash */}             


<CardItem.Info>
                    <CardItem.Icons>
                        <PlayArrow/>
                        <Add/>
                        <ThumbUpAltOutlined/>
                        <ThumbDownAltOutlined/>
                    </CardItem.Icons>
                    <CardItem.ItemInfoTop/>
                    <CardItem.Description>
                    To fulfill his dreams of becoming a legendary Hunter like his dad, 
                    a young boy must pass a rigorous examination and find his missing father.
                    </CardItem.Description>
                    <CardItem.Genre>Action</CardItem.Genre>
                </CardItem.Info>
            </CardItem>

    )
}
```

Components (child)

```
import React from 'react';
import {Container,CardPicture,Info,Icons,Description,ItemInfoTop,Genre} from './styles/card-item';


export default function CardItem({ children, ...restProps }) {
    
      return <Container {...restProps}>{children}</Container>  
}


----------
CardItem.CardPicture = function CardItemCardPicture({ ...restProps }) {
    return (
        <CardPicture {...restProps} />
        )
}
----------


CardItem.Info= function CardItemInfo({ children, ...restProps }) {
    return <Info {...restProps}>{children}</Info>;
}

CardItem.Icons= function CardItemIcons({ children, ...restProps }) {
    return <Icons {...restProps}>{children}</Icons>;
}

CardItem.ItemInfoTop= function CardItemInfoTop({ children, ...restProps }) {
    return <ItemInfoTop {...restProps}>
       <span>22 minutes</span>
       <span id="limit">13+</span>
       <span>2001</span>

    {children}</ItemInfoTop>;
}

CardItem.Description= function CardItemDescription({ children, ...restProps }) {
    return <Description {...restProps}>{children}</Description>;
}

CardItem.Genre= function CardItemGenre({ children, ...restProps }) {
    return <Genre {...restProps}>{children}</Genre>;
}
```

styled component (CSS)

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Container=styled.div`
    width:225px;
    height:120px;
    background-color:#000000;
    margin-right:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;



    &:hover
    {
        
        width:325px;
        height:300px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 13px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.22); 
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 13px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.22);
    } 

`

export const CardPicture=styled.img`
     width:100%;
    height:100%
    object-fit:cover; 

    /*&:hover
    {
        height:140px;
    }

`

export const Info=styled.div`
   
`

export const Icons=styled.div`
 color:white;  
`

export const Description=styled.div`
  
`

export const ItemInfoTop=styled.div`
  
`

export const Genre=styled.div`
  
`
```

Comment: Can you show code for `/styles/card-item` -> `CardPicture` ?

Comment: And, what clues do you get from console log and network activities?
I assume those dashes are not in your code?